# Parsing xml file in django

Tags: python, xml, django

I've an xml document on my project folder and i've problem with extraction of values of an attribute of an element.

My xml file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<results filename="/home/maker/media/image" syncfile="/home/maker/media/synchro.xml">
    <readbit number="1" frame="10" bit="0" score="-0.483138" status="n" />
    <readbit number="2" frame="20" bit="1" score="0.416175" status="n" />
    <readbit number="3" frame="30" bit="0" score="-0.457450" status="n" />
    <readbit number="4" frame="40" bit="1" score="0.597008" status="y" />
    ....
</results>
```

What i tried in my view to get all values of the attribut bit:

```
def parse(request):
    xmldoc = minidom.parse('synchro.xml')
    readbitlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('readbit')
    elements = []
    for s in readbitlist :
        x = s.attributes['bit'].value
        elements.append(x)
    return render(request, 'parse.html', {'elements': elements})
```

In my template:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> Mark </title>
</head>
<body>
 {% for element in elements %}
 <p> {{ element }} </p>
 {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Comment: So what goes wrong?  Do you get an error? If so, which one?

Comment: I don't get any error, I get an empty page.

Answer (score 2):

The list values is empty becuse the populated list is elements, try this:

```
def parse(request):
    xmldoc = minidom.parse('synchro.xml')
    readbitlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('readbit')
    values = []
    for s in readbitlist :
        x = s.attributes['bit'].value
        values.append(x)
    return render(request, 'parse.html', {'values': values})
```

Comment: In my code it's correct, i just forget to replace values with elements while copying and writing my question. So it isn't working

Comment: I will delete the answer then.

Comment: Do you know if the xml file is found? the code should work. try using:`import os
from project.settings import BASE_DIR
file_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'relative_path')` or an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

I am parsing the XML files with The ElementTree XML API:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

It makes it very straightforward.

To parse the XML in your case:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def parse(request):
    xmldoc = minidom.parse('synchro.xml')
    root = xmldoc.getroot()
    elements = []
    for readbit in root.findall('readbit'):
        # get the attribute with value equal 'bit'
        bit = country.get('bit')
        elements.append(bit)
    return render(request, 'parse.html', {'elements': elements})
```